# Windows CE vs Windows XP Embedded

Tags: .net, windows

I am developing a device that will continuously collect data from a PLC and store the data in a database as well as over the network. The device has to be very reliable. I decided to use a fanless PC, thin client or nettop is the appropriate nomenclature I guess, and now I am trying to decide what OS to install. As much as I would like to use Linux, the application will be developed using .NET so I have to go with Windows. I have found [this](http://www.windowsfordevices.com/c/a/Windows-For-Devices-Articles/Choosing-between-Windows-CE-and-Windows-XP-Embedded/) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838646(WinEmbedded.5).aspx). Which OS has a higher reliability. If I were to go with Windows XP Embedded, could I not just use the regular Windows XP instead? Thanks.

Comment: I think there's a huge licensing cost between CE and XP that you might want to consider. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/standard/aa731327.aspx#myth6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your product budget. I was visiting a few times Real-Time & Embedded Computing Conferences and found that most developers are using Windows XP Embedded. [2.0 .Net Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c4837dad-5719-4b63-8752-cb0a65802329&displaylang=en) is supported, as well it is possible to install [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 on Windows XP Embedded Service Pack 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use Linux. I did exactly that. I run Linux Ubuntu on a VIA embedded PC. I target my app to .NET 2 using Visual Studio. Mono is pretty compatible. Only a few gotchas so far. Nice thing about Linux is that you can host VNC and SAMBA and then you can have full access to the 'appliance' Obviously with XPE as well. CE not. Bonus is that you can still run on any Win platform for debugging, actual deployment, demos, etc.